# Obstructions to being a trivial line bundle over itself

Tags: gn.general-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $X$ be a geodesic metric space. Are there known local obstructions to the existence of a (bi-Lipschitz) homeomorphism between $X$ and $X\times \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: I think one obstruction would be an existence of $k$ such that each $x\in X$ has a basis of nested neighborhoods $\{U_i\}$ with the property $H_k(U_i)=0\neq H_k(U_i-\{x\})$. Here $H_k$ is $k$-th homology. Homotopy groups would also do. Are you looking for something else?

Comment: @Igor : It may be close to what I need. Can you elaborate? Perhaps you can make an answer out of your comment?

Comment: It is more difficult than I initially thought. Do you know anything about the local homology $H_k(X, X-\{x\})$? I gather in your setting each point $x\in X$ has a contractible neighborhood but the link at $x$ can be complicated. Is there any homological information about the link?

Comment: I do not have any info about the local homology. But if it is necessary, some info can be obtained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A homological obstruction that I mentioned in the comments can be extracted from  [On homotopical and homological $Z_n$-sets](https://arxiv.org/abs/1002.2802)  by Taras Banakh, Robert Cauty, and Alex Karassev.

This is a long paper but we won't need to know much. 
Given an abelian group $G$, a point $x\in X$ is a *$G$-homological $Z_n$-set* if 
$H_k(X, X-\{x\}; G)=0$ for all $k\le n$. The definition reduces to the one given on page 1 because $H_k(X, X-\{x\}; G)=H_k(U, U-\{x\}; G)$ for any open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ by excision in homology. For example, $0\in \mathbb R$ is a $Z_0$-set but not a $Z_1$-set.

Now suppose $G$ is $\mathbb Q$ or $\mathbb Z_p$, and $X$ is a [Tychonov space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tychonoff_space). 
Theorem 6.1 implies that if a point $x\in X$ is a $G$-homological $Z_n$-set, then the point $(x,0)$ is a $G$-homological $Z_{n+1}$-set in $X\times \mathbb R$.

Therefore, if  **every** point of $X$ is a $Z_n$-set, and a neighborhood of some $x\in X$ is homeomorphic to a neighborhood of $(y,t)\in X\times \mathbb R$, then $n=n+1$, and hence $n=\infty$. The latter is impossible if $x\in X$ is not a $Z_{n+1}$-set, which gives an obstruction.

Note that no obstruction occurs when $X$ is the product of infinitely many copies of $\mathbb R$, and in fact, in this case $X$ is homeomorphic to $X\times \mathbb R$.

To apply the above one only needs to check whether the local homology is trivial (over $\mathbb Q$ or $\mathbb Z_p$). Computing the local homology is not necessary.

Answer (score 4):

Many nice geodesic metric spaces have finite Hausdorff dimension and then 
the spaces $X$ and $X\times\mathbb R$ are not (locally) bi-Lipschitz homeomorphic since ${\rm dim}_H(X\times\mathbb R)={\rm dim}_H(X)+1$ (see this [post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/189270/hausdorff-dimension-of-r-x-x))
and bi-Lipschitz mappings preserve the Hausdorff dimension.

Comment: The spaces $X$ I have in mind all have infinite Hausdorff dimension and some of them are homeomorphic to $X \times \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Could you be more specific? The questions seems too general.

Comment: The metric spaces I am dealing with are asymptotic cones of groups. So they have transitive groups of isometries, etc. Most of them have infinite dimension (in any sense of that word).